# Why am I getting "verifying xros 1.0.simruntime" on M1 Mac even after uninstalling Xcode Beta and Xcode clean?

Tags: xcode, macos, visionos

I am facing an unwanted issue on the M1 Mac. Even if I don't have Xcode running/open, I get the below process:

[image]

I have already cleaned my Mac and reinstalled Xcode but I still get this. During this process, Mac doesn't work anymore and I have to restart my PC.

Does anyone else also face this? If yes, then how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have any version of VisionOS installed? You can find it in `Xcode -> Settings -> Platforms`.

If you have, try to delete it because the Xcode Release version (15.1 - 15C65) does not support this OS yet. You need the beta version to download it.